# Get Record element in Flow does not get the current values

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

i am currently seeing some weird behaviour in a Salesforce flow.
The screen flow has got a lightning component in it which is a custom build picklist that updates a Salesforce Picklist when the value is changed. 
I tested it and the related picklist is really updated by the apex controller when a picklist change occurs.

The lightning component also has a onInit method that gives me the current value of the related picklist. This also works when i update the picklist via the update record element in a flow.

Now comes the odd part: When i update the related picklist from the lightning component via an apex controller and navigate one screen back the value is still in the related picklist but if i navigate again to the next screen the value is gone and the onInit return a null value. (I also checked in the related picklist and it is there gone too). Is the getRecord element of a flow not getting the current values?!

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. :D
Really really looking forward to your answers.

The methods of the lightning component

```
getCurrentValue : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    if(cmp.get('v.recordId') != null && typeof cmp.get('v.recordId') != "undefined" && cmp.get('v.recordId') != ''){
        var action = cmp.get("c.getCurrentValue");
        action.setParams({
            "objectName": cmp.get("v.object"),
            "pickListFieldName": cmp.get("v.field"),
            "recordId": cmp.get("v.recordId")
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.defaultvalue", response.getReturnValue());
                this.fillPicklist(cmp, event, helper);
            }else{
                alert("Es gab ein Problem mit Ihrer Internetverbindung.");
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }else{
        this.fillPicklist(cmp, event, helper);
    }

},

updateRecord : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.updateObject");
    action.setParams({
        "objectName": cmp.get("v.object"),
        "pickListFieldName": cmp.get("v.field"),
        "recordId": cmp.get("v.recordId"),
        "updateValue": cmp.get("v.outputvalue")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

        }else{
            alert("Es gab ein Problem mit Ihrer Internetverbindung.");
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

The related apex controller:

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static void updateObject(String objectName, String pickListFieldName, Id recordId, String updateValue){
    List<sObject> list_object = Database.query('SELECT Id, ' +pickListFieldName +' FROM ' +objectName +' WHERE Id = :recordId');
    SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName); 
    DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();

    for (sObject obj: list_object){

        obj.put(pickListFieldName,updateValue);

    } 

    System.debug('updateValue: ' +updateValue);

    update list_object;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String getCurrentValue(String objectName, String pickListFieldName, Id recordId){
    List<sObject> list_object = Database.query('SELECT Id, ' +pickListFieldName +' FROM ' +objectName +' WHERE Id = :recordId');
    SObjectType objectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName); 
    DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();

    for (sObject obj: list_object){

        obj.get(pickListFieldName);

    } 

    System.debug('returnValue: ' +(String)list_object[0].get(pickListFieldName));

    return (String)list_object[0].get(pickListFieldName);
}
```

The screens in the flow where i navigate back and force.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question, but [this](https://unofficialsf.com/design-proposal-how-lightning-screen-field-components-work-with-next-and-previous/) is a detailed explanation of some of the subtleties of current Before and Next behavior: